# Nginx access log file path

Tags: nginx

This is my `default.conf`. I specify the access.log and error.log path. And I use docker to build it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/test/access-$year-$month-$day.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test2/error.log;

    sendfile off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When I builded it and up. I got the error message.

```
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/log/nginx/test2/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

How can I automatically generate the file path? This is my docker-compose, [Github](https://github.com/lighter/php-nginx-docker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because the `test2` directory doesn't exists. Nginx will not create this automatically for you. So you need to create it using below commands in your Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx/test2 /var/log/nginx/test
```

Comment: I know I need to create the folder first. Can I auto generate the folder?

Comment: No, because nginx won't start without the folder being there. So either you put a SH file which does that and launch nginx.