# How can change Nginx default log file location in docker setting

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm very new to docker and trying build docker compose with multiple service/app, also set the log file place separately.

If I run `docker compose up` will cause the `open() file error` like

```
FPM-nginx  | 2022/10/06 01:40:54 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
FPM-nginx  | nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

According relative answer, I've try adding the new command in `Dockerfile` but still causing the error.

The answers tried
[Nginx access log file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473929/nginx-access-log-file-path)

The answers tried 2
[Nginx log location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328489/nginx-log-location)

Currently `Dockerfile docker-compose.yml nginx.conf` like below

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/ \           <<<<<<<<< This is new add
    touch /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log \     <<<<<<<<< This is new add
    touch /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/access.log \    <<<<<<<<< This is new add
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip

WORKDIR /var/www/FPM
```

`nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/FPM/public;
    error_log /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: FPM-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/FPM
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www/FPM

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.1-alpine
    container_name: FPM-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www/FPM
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

I've also tried place

```
    error_log /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/access.log;
```

under `location /` but still cause the error

```
location / {
    error_log /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've multiple issues with you docker and docker-compose files.

According to your docker-compose.yml, when you would be doing `docker-compose up` you'll have two containers running one brought up from the docker image built at the time and the other brought up from public `nginx:1.23.1-alpine` image. The first image built will have the `/var/www/FPM/log/nginx/` folder along with the `error.log` and `access.log` files but `docker-compose up` will overwrite the content because of this line:

```
volumes:
  - ../src:/var/www/FPM
```

That being said, you don't even need that folder and those files in the first (`app`) container in the first place. You need them in the `nginx` container. So you can remove these lines from the Dockerfile:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/ \ 
    touch /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log \
    touch /var/www/FPM/log/nginx/access.log \
```

Instead, create `error.log` and `access.log` inside your `src` directory or if you would choose at `src/log/nginx/` location for brevity. And mount these files in your docker compose file.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: FPM-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/FPM
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www/FPM

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.1-alpine
    container_name: FPM-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www/FPM
      - ../src/nginx/logs/error.log:/var/www/FPM/log/nginx/error.log;
      - ../src/nginx/logs/access.log:/var/www/FPM/log/nginx/access.log;
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: FPM-app    | [06-Oct-2022 03:51:42] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
| Save the day!